# What causes the very dark brown and black color of some antique oak?

Tags: finishing, coloring, antique

In the Britain, there is a great deal of antique oak furniture and even room wood paneling that is very dark brown and black, sometimes with red undertones, and without the typical golden hues of modern oak.  What causes this oak to have this dark brown color?  Is it the aging of the wood, the aging of the finish (stain, oil, wax, varnish, etc), the normal color of some local variety of oak, was it stained originally in this dark color somehow, or something else?  These items mostly appear to be from pre-1900s.  Examples at the bottom.

The information I can find from retailers of oak furniture, woodworking books, DIY instructional sites, and oak as a material have all pertained to current woodworking processes rather than old processes.  I have found descriptions on the effects of age on current processes over years and maybe decades, but not centuries, and again that would be for modern processes and materials, not these antiques.

Examples:

- https://www.sellingantiques.co.uk/977450/18th-century-oak-box-settle/

[image: Antique oak settle]

- https://www.sellingantiques.co.uk/1004012/a-17th-century-panelled-oak-coffer/

[image: Antique oak coffer]

- 17th century [Globe Room](https://yeoldereinedeerinn.co.uk/pub-globe-history) of the [Ye Olde Reine Deer Inn](https://yeoldereinedeerinn.co.uk/gallery) in Banbury, UK

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. As an experienced SEer I have no hesitation in asking, what research did you do prior to posting the Q?

Comment: I searched google, read some pages, and wikipedia.  I also asked some acquaintances familiar with woodworking and the staff of a woodworking store.  Most described stains but the samples and pictures do not appear to have the same color. I am not familiar with such avenues being described in SE questions

Comment: SE Questions should show [background research you've tried ...that... wasn't enough to solve your problem](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error). It's not sufficient to just have done so, it needs to at least be outlined in the body of the Q for multiple reasons, no. 1 of which is so that potential respondents don't post links to things the OP has already seen (but didn't satisfactorily answer the query).

Comment: If you want this effect, google ‘fume white oak’.

Comment: The link to question standards really shouldn't use "any" as a qualifier for "research" if it is required!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Natural effects, the wood itself**
As touched on in some previous Answers, wood naturally changes colour over time. This 'base effect' so to speak is primarily due to UV light exposure.

The natural colour change due to light essentially works in two directions: lighter woods tending to darken, darker woods tending to lighten. Oak is one of the former.

There are other natural effects with certain species and oak is one of those. This can be seen by the dark colouring of the underside of the lid's two boards and other parts of the interior, which would of course not have been exposed to much light.

**Tannin reaction**
And in addition to the above, oak is famous for its high tannin content and this will account for *some* of the particularly dark colouring in very old oak furniture pieces — tannins react with iron to produce iron tannate which is a permanent black compound. This is what creates the blackish staining around nails and other iron/steel fasteners in wood.

But where the tannic acid content is particularly high it only requires exposure to tiny amounts for a reaction to occur, for example any iron or iron salts dissolved in water used to wipe down a piece during routine cleaning. It only requries a single exposure for this to start happening; and contrary to common perception even when a piece is heavily oiled and/or waxed, some of the water can get through to the wood.

Throw in a span of 400+ years and it's not hard to imagine how many chances there have been for some exposure to iron.

**Linseed oil**
In addition to the effects occurring in the wood itself there's also a possible contributing effect if the wood were ever oiled, since in both Europe and America the primary oil used for such purposes was linseed oil.

It's well known that linseed oil immediately deepens the tone of wood but in addition to that it darkens *significantly* over very long timeframes, typically turning from the starting colour of amber or deep orange to various brownish shades, but can sometimes go distinctly reddish (as noted with some period military gunstocks). And in addition to the darkening over time, if raw linseed oil is allowed to cure in the dark it can turn very dark indeed, almost black<sup>1</sup>.

**Dirt and grime**
Anyone who has ever cleaned a very old piece of furniture knows how much dirt can lurk in corners, recesses and carved detail! But this can also build up in natural features of the wood itself such as open grain — and oak is an open-grained species; some of the black colour in the grain lines of the oak settle above is very likely to be grime built up over time, some of which will have been 'locked in' by oiling or waxing over it.

Some combination of all of the above factors is what accounts for the particular dark and sometimes blackish colouring of old oak furniture and panelling in interiors.

**Where it's not of natural origin......**
Because of this dark colouring being so common, it started to become *desirable* for older furniture pieces, as well as panelling and other architectural features, to be this dark. As a result it should come as no surprise that the colour of some oak was 'enhanced' using wood dyes<sup>2</sup>, or coloured finishes because "That's what old oak looks like." Your third link undoubtedly shows examples of this in the pub interiors<sup>3</sup>.

This very dark brown colouring was (and still is) often generically associated with the Jacobean period, hence the presence to this day in finish ranges of "Jacobean Oak" or just "Jacobean" wood stains/dyes and coloured finishes.

---

<sup>1</sup> Curing mostly or entirely in the dark *may* be what accounts for the redder tones.

<sup>2</sup> Starting with the traditional Van Dyke crystals. These somewhat confusingly come from walnut trees :-)

<sup>3</sup> The pieces in the first two links I would judge to be in as-found condition, bar cleaning and a fresh waxing, but there's absolutely no way to be sure from photos. (Note that it may even be impossible to tell in person, hence the number of people, even pros in the trade, who have been and continue to be fooled by clever fakes.)

Comment: Thanks for the wonderfully detailed answer covering different factors. I do not know how old or new all parts of that pub are, but the Globe Room has documentation to the 17th century which I clarified in the question.

Comment: You're welcome. Re. the pub, there are multiple instances of what has to be modern interior woodworking (framing elements etc.) and numerous newer furniture pieces (some possibly quite modern, despite the 'traditional' styling) which all feature much the same colouration. That's a sure sign that dyeing and/or coloured varnish was heavily relied upon :-)

Comment: I came across a technique called fuming (with ammonia) and by the looks of some examples, I think this could be a big factor.  Additionally, smoke from candles, fireplaces (wood and coal), and tobacco could have contributed to the coloring at least via grime.  I added this to your answer

Comment: Fuming Wood can be exposed to ammonia fumes which reacts with the wood's tannins to greatly darken the color. White oak was particularly used due to its high tannin content and such treated wood may be called fumed oak, fumigated oak, or smoked oak. This effect penetrates quite deep (1/8 inch or more). In addition to fuming, historically ammonia could also be purportedly brushed on but I am still lacking information on that. Fuming could even applied to an entire room by leaving bowls of ammonia within. This treatment was well known by the late Victorian era (19th century) but perhaps earlier

Comment: Tobacco smoke and even animal urine has some ammonia that could perhaps cause the effect.

Comment: Fuming can most definitely get oak to turn very dark, which would then be deepened (and the colour enhanced) by finish applied on top, particularly linseed oil. However before a certain date it's not likely — the main thing to consider is that period depictions of interiors and furniture tend to show an original light colour. And prior to the 19th c. ammonia at any a decent concentration might have been unavailable. So without definitive knowledge of its use historically *for this purpose* it's mere speculation that it was used to deliberately produce darkened oak, prior to the late 1800ish.

Comment: "brushing ammonia solutions directly on oak was a well-known darkening method by the late 19th century" or the late Victorian era
https://artsandcraftshomes.com/interiors/fumed-oak-wood-stains

Comment: 1849: "A new oak carved arm-chair exposed to the vapours of ammonia, will in about twelve hours have all the appearance of its being made 200 years since; and any other wood similarly exposed, will obtain the appearance of oak."
Source: William Laxton The Civil engineer and architect's journal, Volume 12, February 1849 page 60
http://www.woodworkinghistory.com/glossary_ammonia_fuming.htm

Comment: Sorry I thought it was clear when I said its use historically I meant its use prior to the 19th c. when we know for sure that ammonia was available and was used for this. Without ammonia at a decent concentration the technique might have been unknown, since the effect is so much slower (even modern household ammonia is very slow compared to the strengths recommended for doing this in 20th c. guides). You should write a second Answer covering the use of ammonia as another way to darken oak artificially & your discoveries of 19th c. sources showing its known use by the 1800s, I'll upvote it :-)

Comment: I am curious about the appearance differences between the iron-tannin reaction in your answer and the ammonia-tannin reaction.  The iron seems much easier to do

Comment: The iron acetate | tannins reaction tends to yield greys to black, the colour only moved towards something 'warmer' by the finish application (still with a noticeable greyness underneath). Generally ammonia fuming innately gives colours in the brown range, all the way to a sort of deep chocolate at the extreme. The differences (particularly differences between pieces taken from the same board) are probably best judged in person and so you can do the direct side-by-side comparison. This would be something v easy to arrange at home, with possibly household ammonia being the only needed purchase.

Answer (score 1):

**Ammonia Fuming (and perhaps brushing)**

A partial answer may be fuming wood; the answer is partial because it is unclear if this method (or similar ones) were used before the mid-Victorian era. Ammonia fuming appears to be popular in the late Victorian era and some sources mention earlier brushing of ammonia, but with few details.  Sources [1](http://www.woodworkinghistory.com/glossary_ammonia_fuming.htm) & [2](https://artsandcraftshomes.com/interiors/fumed-oak-wood-stains).

Wood can be exposed to ammonia fumes which [reacts with the wood's tannins](https://canadianhomeworkshop.com/1546/tips-tools/techniques-tools-resources/restoration-workshop-darkening-wood) to greatly darken the color. White oak was particularly used due to its high tannin content and such treated wood may be called fumed oak, fumigated oak, or smoked oak. This effect [penetrates](https://woodandshop.com/how-to-fume-ammonia-fuming-experiment-cheap-ammonia/) quite deep ([1/8 inch or more](https://youtu.be/RkldSI2Havw?si=sUKZR429mURG-pk0&t=291)) and can be very dark almost black. Here's a [color scale.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia_fuming#/media/File:Fuming_chart.jpg)  It affects the [sapwood differently.](https://woodworkersinstitute.com/reviews/2023/02/tudor-gothic-panel/) Fuming could even applied to an [entire room by leaving bowls of ammonia within.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia_fuming)  Purportedly, this effect would be noticed in barns where the ammonia in [animal urine](https://www.finewoodworking.com/1997/10/01/fuming-with-ammonia) had a similar effect unintentionally to their pens.  I wonder if the ammonia in tobacco products would have a similar effect over time, but haven't found a source supporting this.

I suppose there would also be general staining and grime over time from from pipes/cigars, fireplaces (coal and wood), and candles, but need some sources describing how powerful this effect could be.