# What would cause wood filler to turn black when refinishing oak floor?

Tags: refinishing, filler, oak, flooring

I was refinishing some old oak floors in rough condition, and troweled in Duraseal wood filler after a rough sand.  Mostly, it worked fine, but in some places in one room, the filler turned dark or black in the cracks between boards, or in nail holes.  In one spot near a wall, the filler turned black in a blotchy pattern in the middle of a board.  It's top-nailed quarter-inch red oak, and seems to have taken a lot of dog pee over the years.  Many of the boards were badly cupped prior to sanding, and big gaps exist between many boards.  We scrubbed with 3% hydrogen peroxide, using a small plastic bristle brush, to lighten the urine stains a bit, prior to filling.  The floor dried for about ten hours before I troweled the filler.

I wondered what is causing the filler to turn dark in places.  Could it be so much urine soaked into the wood that it's reacting with the filler?  Or residual peroxide?  We aren't expecting cosmetic perfection, but worry about how the mechanical properties of the filler might be affected by whatever is turning it black.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Did you do any prior searching for information about oak and it turning black? This tendency in oak is widely documented online. And actually it (and the usual remedy) are referenced multiple times here in previous Answers, including one that is still on the first page here as it was only added on the 17th of this month.

Comment: [Here's that question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/14936/what-causes-the-very-dark-brown-and-black-color-of-some-antique-oak) to make it easy for you.

Comment: My question is not about why oak turns black over decades or hundreds of years.  It was about why Duraseal wood filler would turn black, in certain spots, after a few hours, when troweled on an old oak floor during refinishing.  It's the sort of question only a hardwood floor pro is likely to answer, or perhaps another DIY person who encountered the same phenomenon and stumbled onto some explanation.  As I understand, that's the purpose of forums like this.

Comment: Possibly you dismissed the question without actually reading it.  The reference to filler seems clear to me.  I asked the question in this forum because my prior research on cleaning urine stains in old oak floors led to discussion here.  These topics do come up here.

Comment: I did read the Question through and perhaps I did leap ahead to the wrong conclusion in the absence of photos, and due to dark/black staining and oak being so intrinsically linked to a single causative agent. I will note there's a lot of water here — the other 97% of the peroxide solution, the water base of the filler — and that inevitably rings the "tannic acid reaction" alarm bell. If it is *exclusively* the filler itself that has turned dark however then the manufacturers are really the only ones who might be able to tell you what has happened.

Comment: Did the filler turn black immediately after you applied it to the wood or only after you applied new stain to the entire wood surface?